# Photoshop Layer Style to CoreGraphics Code

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, calayer, photoshop

Is there a way to easily export layer styles, created in photoshop, to core graphics code? Maybe a photoshop plugin or a .psd parser for use in xcode. I imagine someone has made (or should make) a process to more easily facilitate the "from design, to code" process. The only thing I could find on google was [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) which takes illustrator files and outputs core graphics code.

Or maybe a third party program similar to [this](http://layerstyles.org/) which creates a familiar layer style interface and exports css code.

Update : Found this today. [MooMaskedIconView](https://github.com/peyton/MOOMaskedIconView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it : http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to apply effects to an image, you can use `Core Image`, which comes with 48 filters. Currently there isn’t a way to build custom filters on the iOS platform, that's a drawback … But to get started I sugesst you to take a look at Ray Wenderlichs tutorial [Beginning Core Image in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5).

Another approach is using 3rd party libs. For example [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/), which has a huge feature set :)

Answer (score -2):

I use Save for Web & Devices. Png-24 keep the opacity but there is no facilities for layers. When you save, the LNG becomes what you are looking at. So it's easy to keep several layers in the same Photoshop file.

Comment: Currently I export from photoshop as png images. But I would like to export to Core Graphics Code

Comment: From my research, there is currently no way to export a Photoshop Style to CoreGraphics code. Maybe someone could write a plugin that will do this?